# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Database Administrators breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 17         21
Users destroyed                                 124          0
Users deleted                                    32          0
Users contacted                                  21          0
User banned from review                           3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           293      5,576
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               13      1,564
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        163      3,191
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                1      1,442
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                15      9,191
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              298     11,735
Tags merged                                       6          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            10          0
Tag synonyms created                             10          0
Revisions redacted                                8          0
Questions unprotected                             2          1
Questions reopened                               98         66
Questions protected                               1         26
Questions migrated                               27         90
Questions merged                                 10          0
Questions flagged⁴                               56      1,160
Questions closed                                518      2,821
Question flags handled⁴                         445        771
Posts unlocked                                    4         40
Posts undeleted                                  50        246
Posts locked                                     18        351
Posts deleted⁵                                1,364      5,016
Posts bumped                                      0      8,728
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                              257          0
Comments flagged                                101      3,737
Comments deleted⁶                            11,349      6,558
Comment flags handled                         2,428      1,410
Bounties canceled                                 7          0
Answers flagged                                  63      2,656
Answer flags handled                          2,242        477
All comments on a post moved to chat             31          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Adding one to the deleted comments for next year. But thanks for the update